# Transfer a google Drive to a different user in a different subdomain

Tags: google-drive-api

I am looking to transfer users from one domain to a different domain within our Google Apps.  We don't want users to manually move their files and we cannot have our admins transfer them (we have 50K + users to move).
Is there any way within Google's API's that I can program a method to transfer files within an executable?  Please if there is a way to do it in .Net that would be most desired.

Comment: you cant transfer ownership to a different domain unless is part of a multiple domains gapps account.

Answer (score 0):

See the [permissions.insert()](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert) reference. There's a .Net sample on that page that should get you started.

Comment: This initially only appears to allow permission settings on individual files (fileid as a parameter).  I need something that is user based as some users could potentially have thousands of files needing to be transferred.

Comment: If this is all within the same Google Apps instance why aren't you just changing the user's primary SMTP address (thus allowing them to keep all their data). See https://support.google.com/a/answer/182084?hl=en

Comment: Transferring Drive files is a per-file API operation. You could use batch to speed things up some but it's still an API call per file/folder.